# Customize the user interface in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I understand how to brand my login form but how to customize the workflow that Azure provides?
Currently the Sign-up form looks like this:

[image]

Which is really unlogical. The text boxes under 'Verificatiecode verzenden' (Send verification code) are only useful after the code has received and filled in.
How to customize this part to create a better working workflow:
`Add email address -> Send code -> Fill in code and verify --> Fill in additional user details.`

**Edit**:
As recommended by Brad I dived into `Identity Experience Framework`. An 'intimidating' framework is a big understatement ;(
I watched these videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4svy-vB4AaxRunWQkxOe8h3zP9jAzS5Z and followed the steps mentioned here:

- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki/LocalAndSocialAccount-Sign-In-and-Sign-Up-policy
- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup

I'm just at the point that I only want to mimic what I currently have using the 'normal' user flows:

- Log-in using Email
- Log-in using Facebook
- Log-in using Google

The login screen looks the same, I have the email and password buttons and the Facebook and Google buttons, but when I log in with Google I get an error about grant-type not set.
And this is all without trying the split.xml.
I'm so lost in understanding AAD B2C. It should make live easier for developers but I find it very complicated, hard to modify and hard to get the profile data I  need and to keep the data in sync.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this with `User Flows`, you must use the Custom User Interface features, and Javascript to control how and when those fields are displayed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow#enable-javascript

Optionally, you can conduct a similar flow using the `Identity Experience Framework` (Custom Policies) with either Javascript or where you use two different `Self Asserted` profiles to move from screen to screen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-trust-frameworks

Taking the leap from `User Flows` to the `Identity Experience Framework` can be intimidating, but would give you the most control in your user experience.

Comment: Thanks @brad-c We'll try that and get back here with the results.

Comment: I updated my post. I tried what you suggested and I can read that it should work, but I can't even get the very basics running let alone any customizations.

Comment: You may have some luck starting out with this tool: https://aka.ms/iefsetup - Otherwise, we can try to figure out what problems you are having. Did you try to customize just the User Flows first with Javascript?

Comment: Thanks Brad, again for your quick reply. I'll have a look at the link you provided. I did not try to customize the User Flow with Javascript. Is it easier and do you have a working example? My goals are to split the signup form and also let the user fill in the email address when it is not passed from the social provider.

Comment: I haven't tried to customize a User Flow, but anything would seem easier than the Identity Experience Framework. If I get some time this weekend, I can try to put together an example of what you're trying to accomplish if you don't beat me to it.

Comment: Using the setup I do get a lot of custom policies that work using the 'Run now' option in the portal, but I can't get my Blazor Wasm app to use them. It keeps using the 'old' one, which doesn't work.   I'm working on this for another full day (again) and made no progress, so I'll leave it for a few days.    I also dislike Javascript so I think/hope you will beat me to it.